# SocketTimeoutException : null while opening New Spring Starter Project

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-boot, microservices, eclipse-jee

SocketTimeoutException : null while opening New Spring Starter Project

[image]

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40
Path=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\..
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change the network setting in the STS.

```
Select Window Tab -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connection and change the setting.
```

Set Active Provider to manual then edit the host and port details in proxy entries. Apply the setting and click ok.

This worked for me. Hope it works for you

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the network setting in the STS.

Select Window Tab -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connection and change the setting.

Set Active Provider to DIRECT

Answer (score 0):

Select Window Tab -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connection and change the setting.

Set Active Provider to DIRECT

Answer (score 0):

Try to start apache tomcat, after starting tomcat your issue should  be resolve.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).